# setTimeout function in javascript

Tags: settimeout, alert, showmodaldialog

Here is what I want to do.

Is there a way I can throw a temporary alert which fades away in 4 sec so user knows he has clicked the button and the results are getting generated.

Why all this:
When user clicks a button, I retrieve id's of checked rows and build a dynamic html table to display the results in a showmodal dialog window.each row in seperate divs.

Why I  used setTimeout:
I noticed that the showmodal dialog would appear before the html was built resulting at times with an empty page. So to give my dynamic html time to build I call the setTimeout function to call another function "setTimeout('CallModFunction()',4000);" and within this I call the showmodal dialog, so the html displays perfectly on the dialog window.

My question is: 
Is there a way I can throw a temporary alert which fades away in 4 sec so user knows he has clicked the button and the results are getting generated.

Comment: Make a modal and then have it go away when you are done building your dynamic html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Noty: http://needim.github.com/noty/